# Did I buy the wrong size hybrid bike?

Tags: bike-fit, hybrid-bike

I am a male who's 5'11" tall with an inseam of 32". Last summer I bought an Evo Grand Rapid 3 bike with an XL frame, 22"/56cm from a bike shop. I realized that the bike I bought is a hybrid bike, not a road bike. I've been looking at the road bike charts for fit where it recommends 56cm frame for a 5'11" tall person.

The manufacturer's guidelines are:
L 20": 5'11" - 6'1"
XL 22": 6'1" - 6"4
I found that out later.

When I tested the bike, I did the following:

I have 1 inch of standover clearance. While standing on top of the top tube, I am able to lift the bike exactly 1 inch off the ground.

I am not too concern with the saddle height. Sitting at the lowest point of the saddle, I am able to stand tip-toe. I can comfortably put my heel on the pedal at the 6 o'clock position without a knee bend, put the balls of my foot on the pedal at the 6 o'clock position with a slight knee bend. To achieve this, my seat must be lowered to the lowest point.

I am more concern about the reach. Not sure if I am overthinking, but to reach the handlebar with a slight bend on my arms, my torso need to bend 45 degree relative to the hips, and my arms are angled at 90 degree relative to the torso. Nevertheless, I feel slightly stretched out. I wish the handlebars are just 3cm closer to my body.

I am not sure if the Grand Rapid 3 is a more aggressive bike and that my horizontal posture is intentional. I am used to riding a hybrid bike with a raiser stem and riser handlebar that allows me to achieve a more upright back.

To combat this, do you think it's a good idea to install a handlebar riser that rises the stem? I heard many people say that it is a bad idea because it impacts steering. However, I suspect that they are coming from the road bike perspective.

Will a handle bar riser like this one decrease the effective reach?

[image: Handlebar Riser]

This is the Evo Grand Rapid 3
[image: Evo Grand Rapid 3]

This is the bike I'm used to riding
[image]

Comment: The bike you are used to riding has a very relaxed upright geometry. Notice how the saddle is much lower than the handlebars. The slightly above, like on the first photo, is more common on sport bikes even though mountain bikes these days are more upright than they used to be and for getting down hard terrsin the saddle is dropped down.

Comment: Agreed with the above, maybe more to do with geometry and bike style rather than size. If you feel there is the right amount of room between the saddle and handlebar and not like you overetend to reach the bar (too large) or feel that your legs are too close to the handlebar (too small) the rest is about geometry. You can achieve a more relaxed stance by raising the stem, yes, it's regularly done. Some stems are also adjustable in height. Bear in mind spacer below the stem may require a longer staring tube and therefore a new fork.

Comment: A shorter stem (not extending as far from the steer tube) will have the same effect of raising your upper body as a longer steer tube would.